# Missing modules from python when running py2exe

Tags: python-3.7, py2exe

As I am using Python version 3.7.9 for my project. So I finally need to build an exe file so here I have py2exe version 0.12.0.2 which works for the specified python version. When I try to run this command in the terminal `py -3.7 setup.py` or `python setup.py py2exe`, it starts py2exe but ends with these module missing error:

```
>>>python setup.py py2exe 
running py2exe

10 missing Modules
  ------------------
? __builtin__                         imported from pyHook.cpyHook
? __main__                            imported from bdb, pdb
? _cpyHook                            imported from pyHook.cpyHook
? _frozen_importlib                   imported from importlib, importlib.abc
? _frozen_importlib_external          imported from importlib, importlib._bootstrap, importlib.abc
? _winreg                             imported from platform
? java.lang                           imported from platform
? org.python.core                     imported from copy, pickle
? os.path                             imported from os, pkgutil, pyHook.cpyHook, py_compile, sysconfig, tracemalloc, unittest, unittest.util
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
```

And here I attach the list of packages which are already installed for the python version 3.7.9 :

```
Package                  Version
------------------       --------
altgraph                  0.17.4
cachetools                5.3.2
distlib                   0.3.7
filelock                  3.12.2
importlib-metadata        6.7.0
pefile                    2023.2.7
pip                       23.3.1
platformdirs              4.0.0
py2exe                    0.12.0.2
pyHook                    1.5.1
pyinstaller               5.13.2
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2023.10
python-git                2018.2.1
pywin32                   306
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.2
Send2Trash                1.8.2
setuptools                47.1.0
tk                        0.1.0
typing_extensions         4.7.1
virtualenv                20.25.0
wheel                     0.41.2
zipp                      3.15.0
```

Anybody knows how to fix these errors?

> First my setup file doesn't even run. When digging upon the terminal, I came to know it was executing by latest python version. So I implicitly run the file with my required python version in the terminal. And next is the rest. Could anyone please tell me how to include these missing modules?